# Unable to set preferred domain in Google Search Console for www.example.school.nz

Tags: google-search-console

Google Search Console doesn't seem to see `school.nz` as a top-level domain, and therefore, `example.school.nz` as a root level domain. This means that I can't set the preferred domain to `www.example.school.nz`.

How do I tell Google that `school.nz` is a TLD or make `www.example.school.nz` the preferred domain (or both)?

Comment: You can always use 301 redirect in order to make www.[redacted].school.nz your primary access. Check this to know more about how Google handles top-level domains: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/07/googles-handling-of-new-top-level.html

Comment: It already does redirect. Just trying to get the search listing showing the correct domain (and protocol)

Comment: If you have available just this access, just be patient, Google will take that into the SERPs eventually.

Comment: I agree, if you have 301 redirects in place there is no need to use that feature in Google Search Console.  Just wait a few weeks.

Comment: Presumably you already have both the www and non-www sites verified in GSC? "...showing the correct domain (and protocol)" - Just to clarify, GSC only allows you to set the "preferred _domain_", there is no "preferred _protocol_" option in GSC.

Comment: At least right now `school.nz` is listed on https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat so anyone using that list should recognize it as a valid suffix.